# How Can I get my app id in Telegram API?

Tags: java, api, telegram

I am trying to get my app id from Telegram API by using the method `register.saveDeveloperInfo`, but I cannot find the way to do it.

I'm using de MTProto Java library.

This is what I had done by now:

1. I made my own `register.saveDeveloperInfo` implemmentation in Java.
2. I call the method with the corrects params (https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id)
3. The method returns a true boolean but I have not received the sms with my app_id.
4. When I enter in my app section of the telegram web (https://core.telegram.org/myapp) shows the "Your app is not ready yet" message.

Anyway, I'm trying to use the app_id from the source code of the official client but I can't send or receive message.

Does anyone know how to do it or where can I find more information?

Comment: i did the same, and still waiting the sms =/ 
also tried to send an email to api_support@telegram.org.

lmk if you are able to get the your id

Comment: Hi, did you manage to make it work? How did you send the query? I am stuck getting an INPUT_FETCH_ERROR, which I don't know what means

Comment: @adpoy can you get any solution because i am going to integrate my apps with telegram but its not create new application

Answer (score 5):

You can get your app api_id and app api_hash from [your Telegram app page](https://my.telegram.org/myapp). This is what you'll be using as of this writing. If you are asked a password, provide the mobile phone number you'll be using to develop and Telegram will send you the password.

Comment: have tried this? it's not working when i am creating new application submit form give error it's not creating appId\

Comment: What was your error and what did you do to create the application?

Comment: @UditKumawat I'm getting the same error "API_ID_INVALID". have you found any solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asked a password and Telegram didn't send it to you, try to provide the mobile phone number without "+".

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling any anti-spam software or VPN. Disabling ABP for https://my.telegram.org/apps helped me