# Telegram API - Create New Application Error

Tags: android, forms, telegram, registration

I'm trying to register new app to use the Telegram API, but I'm always getting ERROR message with no tips.

I fill the form and click submit and nothing happened:

[image: form filled]

And when click submit I'm getting error:

[image: error]

Nothing is shown in the browser console. What am I doing wrong?

There's a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878812/how-can-i-get-my-app-id-in-telegram-api), but no solution.

Could anyone help on this?

Comment: I noticed that there is a line says "Please make sure your users understand that your app is using our API and is part of the Telegram ecosystem — this must be mentioned in the app's description." in Obtaining_new_id To-dos. Following these instructions did not help, too

Comment: the same problem. can't find any solution.

Comment: It's working, i think it was telegram issue.

Comment: Same issue, I just enabled add blocker and disabled it again. now It works :/ (Note: I'm still using VPN and I didn't write anything special in my app description)

Comment: Worked in `Incognito` Chrome mode. It was an extension interference.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For those who are still looking for this answer in 2021. The problem is probably that you are using VPN accessing https://my.telegram.org/apps I switched my off and it works now

Comment: Had to disable uBlock to make it work, but idea is the same as in this answer.

Comment: I have disabled my vpn but still not working

Comment: This was definitely the case for me. Removed VPN settings from my MAC and it worked without any hiccup

Comment: It doesn't work for all countries . specially Iran .

Answer (score 17):

Try it with your **phone**. It worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Be careful about the "App title" and "Short name" values. "Short name" should be alpha-numeric, so don't use spaces. Example Form:

> App title:**deneme1508212358**
>
> Short name:**deneme**
>
> URL:
>
> Platform:**Desktop**
>
> Description:

Comment: For me this is  the answer, the name should be in that format

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. I think the developers are too lazy put error specific messages there. :p

Comment: Surprisingly, I convert all the uppercase characters to lowercase, and the creation turned success... don't know why

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue too. I disabled my Ad-Blocker and UBlock Origin, my VPN wasn't enabled - but I still received "ERROR" when submitting the form.

What did work was to open the url in incognito mode. It then worked first time.

Comment: Exactly, my case is cause Ad-block. i had turn off and working

Answer (score 7):

Do not use the web from Computer! **use any cellphone android or ios phone** and use the web.

Comment: Tried this but It errored again, waited a little and resubmitted the form without changing anything and it worked! Used VPN + phone number which was not from the same country as of the VPN.

Comment: Worth noting: for some reason even changing in Chrome from desktop to mobile page version does not help. Only visiting from an Android phone. Amazing site design.

Answer (score 5):

My phone country numbr is **+86(CN)**.

When I use a VPN in Singapore, it always return "**ERROR**".

And the problem is solved when I switched my VPN to Hong Kong.

So I wonder if it may detect the mobile phone country number and IP address?

Still, if you're not using a VPN, you can check the adds blocking and the "Short name" value (Which must be alpha-numeric).

I tried all these methods but only changing my VPN ip works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah, both Hong Kong and Taiwan IP works for +86

Answer (score 4):

It seems is an issue from my.telegram.org side, I kept clicking the Create Application button with the same information and on one of those attempts it worked, so I don't think it is a vpn or ad blocker issue, its an issue with the site, so keep trying until it works !!

Answer (score 4):

If you are iranian do this:

1. First I changed my DNS and used https://shecan.ir/
2. then I enabled my vpn (turkey server)

Answer (score 3):

I tried changing name and short name of my app
**Try giving it a unique name and short name it shall work.**

Answer (score 3):

The phone numbers must be the same country ip (be carful using VPN)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

**Working as of 1st January 2023**

I've managed to register new App in PC under VPN (IP with another country that same with my registered number origin country) with following form details:

```
App title: TestApp1
Short name: testapp1
URL: N/A (Fill nothings here)
Platform: Desktop
Description: N/A (Fill nothings here)
```

OS: Windows 11
Browser: Microsoft Edge (InPrivate mode without any plugins installed)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Opening incognito mode in Chrome + changing name (get rid of - and _ symbols) = and it's worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Brave browser, just turn off your shields for that page.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too.
You should not use **VPN**.
You can use **VPS** instead and the problem will be **solved**.

Answer (score 2):

To me the problem resolved by not using the underscore (and anything else but letters) in the shot name.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a proper url in order to use the telegram api. The telegram will provide you an api key from this site (Log in to your Telegram core: [https://my.telegram.org]).
For further assistance kindly refer this [https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id]

Answer (score 1):

Disabled your Ad-Blocker and UBlock Origin and it should work.

If you have a Mac:

1. Open Safari
2. Top Left, click Safari
3. Click Preferences in the drop-down menu
4. Click on Websites and where you see it says, "my.telegram.org" you can change it from "Block and Notify" to "Allow" and then refresh the telegram website and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to create new Telegram APP from different network, for example, connect to VPN or use you mobile carrier internet connection to do it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to login to https://my.telegram.org/apps from the very that country where your phone number registered. I lived in another country and even using VPN to pretend I was in the correct country didn't help. I tried all possible browsers, even clean virtual machine.
I created new telegram account using the phone number registered in the country I was at the moment and tried again. Everything worked like a charm from the very 1st attempt.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check your device location and current session location. This should be the same. Use VPN and check telegram detects your location correctly. If that so, You are on.

Answer (score 1):

close this chrome extension worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use VPN, try to select the platform as "Web". I happened to solve the "error" issue by this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not using a VPN, but choosing "Web" fixed the problem for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me not working too, when I`m trying to create new application. But when I open debugging console in google chrome and try again it worked. Maybe it will help.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30148003)

Answer (score 0):

VPN and Incognito Mode did not help me.
I created new Telegram account based on the phone number of my current country where I am located (btw telegram app allows to use multiple accounts in the same app). Then I successfully logged in to the api website.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Yemen, I used OpenVPN and a files OpenVPN file from [https://www.vpngate.net/](https://vpngate) it changed my country to North Korea, and its works. for all apps, mobile, web and desktop .

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Vivaldi browser. Turns out it works with Google Chrome. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts, the creation of the app was successful.

1. I'm using VPN, IP locate in San Joes US;
2. Just retry submit with different platforms;

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to create a Telegram app using both Chrome and Edge browsers, but was unsuccessful in my initial attempts. The phone number I used for verification is a USA Google Voice number.

However, when I switched to Safari and tried once more, the process initially failed. But upon persistently clicking the 'Create' button 2 to 3 times, I was finally able to successfully create the app.

IP address should be consist with the phone number. I use proxy with the USA ip address and created tg app successfully in Safari.