# Create new application telegram API - Always shows ERROR

Tags: api, telegram, registration

I'm trying to register new app to use the Telegram API, but i'm aways getting ERROR message with no tips.

I fill the form and click submit and nothing happened:

[image: form filled]

And when click submit I'm getting error:

[image: error]

Nothing is shown in the browser console. What i'm doing wrong?
I also tried to do it on my vps.(No VPN at all) > Same Error
I also tried to do it on my android phone. > Same Error

Comment: Just keep on trying. It will create the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new application telegram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104560/create-new-application-telegram-api)

Answer (score 0):

Open URL in your browser's incognito mode

Answer (score -2):

Disable your ad blocker for telegram.