# Telegram API - How to solve create new application error?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I found a post in Stackoverflow, but it's unable to resolve my issue. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104560/create-new-application-telegram-api)

Prooblem screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlILL.png)

Comment: Try short name in alphanumeric format i.e. CoinDance1

Answer (score 0):

**Working as of 1st January 2023**

I've managed to register new App in PC under VPN (IP with another country that same with my registered number origin country).

You can try with following form details:

```
App title: CoinDanceNotice
Short name: CoinDance1
URL: http://api.coindance.cc
Platform: Webb
Description: This app is using Telegram API and is part of the Telegram ecosystem
```

OS: Windows 11
Browser: Microsoft Edge (InPrivate mode without any plugins installed)

Hope this helps to solve your problem =)