# my.telegram.org sends an ERROR when I want to create an API id/hash in API development tools section

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm trying to get my API id/hash to create some bots for telegram , but in the **API developmen tools** section , when I enter my bot informations( name , shortname...) and click on create to get the results , I recieve an error :

**my.telegram.org says ERROR**

I live in Iran and telegram servers are blocked here .

Any solution for this problem?

!! I found the Iranians-only solution which I wrote down below .

Comment: for using creating bots you can just message @botfather in telegram and the official botfather boot will help you create a bot and get an api key for that bot.

Comment: With a VPN I got this error. Without using the VPN it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new application telegram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104560/create-new-application-telegram-api)

Comment: this does not answer the question.  They want an Telegram API key, not a bot API key.

Comment: (to Nabi) No it doesn't . not for Chinese and Iranians .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***NEW and SIMPLE answer :***

- Just ask the bot father (https://t.me/BotFather) to help you create a
  new bot and give you
  the api key . very simple and lovely . (thanks
  Mr.https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485852/john)

1. go to https://t.me/BotFather
2. type /newbot
3. choose a name for your bot
4. choose a username for your bot
5. Done! it will send you the HTTP API key .

[image]

***My OLD answer:*** (***Mosty for countries that have blocked Telegram!***)

- Use good VPNs that can hide your main ip. Telegram's website can find your main ip and will not allow you to use its features, so try different SAFE VPNs until you finally get your api key .(but the better way is to ask the bot father (https://t.me/BotFather)

Comment: select android from the platform worked for me!

Comment: I am sorry, but I would not call that an answer but a workaround. It's utterly horrible some developers release programs which do not handle errors properly, show implicit error messages, and require others to invest precious and priceless time instead of actually working or try to enjoy the short life we all have.

Comment: There is no differnce between a BOT TOKEN API and API ID and API HASH?? This is a wrong answer!

Comment: Hi @aboss, I have been seeing the same issue due to a blocked telegram in my country. I have created the API key and hash using BotFather. When I use the API credentials to work with this through command line, it gives error of network connectivity. Like this, "Server closed the connection: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired
Connection error 1 during auth_key gen: OSError: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired". Do you have any idea in particular of how to connect successfully through command line?

Answer (score 13):

I disable the "AdBlock" extension in the browser and it's work.
That may happen with enabled VPN extension as well
[image]

Comment: I have neither of them and it is still not working...

Comment: You should try using cloudflare warp VPN

Answer (score 5):

In my case the only way to make it work was to switch from Chrome to Safari

Answer (score 5):

The ip address must be in the same country as the mobile phone number of the telegram account when applying

Comment: I live in Iran . telegram servers are blocked here . so what you said is not an answer for Iranians . ( I think you gave me that negative point , I invite you to come to Iran and check both of our answers )

Comment: I tried vpn and that didn't work...

Comment: How about if you have an 888 number?

Answer (score 5):

**Working as of 1st January 2023**

I've managed to register new App in PC under VPN (IP with another country that same with my registered number origin country) with following form details:

```
App title: TestApp1
Short name: testapp1
URL: N/A (Fill nothings here)
Platform: Desktop
Description: N/A (Fill nothings here)
```

OS: Windows 11
Browser: Microsoft Edge (InPrivate mode without any plugins installed)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The ip address and phone number should be in the same country. If you are in countries that prevents you from Telegram such as China. The only way is to use the mobile number of another country (you can use Google Voice, textnow or etc.). By the way, if you use a +86 phone number, you can try using the IP address in Hong Kong

Comment: my account is Chinese number, I can not get telegram API by use Hong Kong VPN