# I got an error when create telegram application

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

On my Telegram site, after filling in the fields, when I click on the submit button, I encounter this problem:
[image]
Does anyone know what the solution is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104560/create-new-application-telegram-api/71888202#71888202 try out this one

Answer (score -1):

You can't create new application with public vpns

Comment: I am from Iran and if I don't use VPN, I can't access the site

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @alirezakarmiyan try using paid vpn like nord or setup your own vpn/proxy server